# Como criar um link simbólico para um código em Python no Linux?

Tags: python, linux

Quero executar um simples código em Python que criei a partir de qualquer local do meu sistema.

Sei que para fazer isso com um *shell script* basta rodar o comando **ln -s /home/usuario/script.sh /usb/bin/script**, porém gostaria de saber como fazer o mesmo com um "codigo.py".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É igual:

```
ln -s /home/usuario/codigo.py /usb/bin/script
```

Comment: Realmente, é o mesmo comando. O erro que eu estava encontrando ao chamar o meu código era por não ter definido o interpretador correto. 
No meu caso, o problema se resolveu ao acrescentar "#!/usr/bin/python2" no início do código.

Obrigado pela ajuda.