# Pegar imagem dentro da pasta storage

Tags: php, laravel, sistema-de-arquivos, laravel-5.2

Estou fazendo o upload de imagens na pasta `storage`, `app/public`, dentro desta criei uma pasta `/banners` e estou fazendo o upload dessas imagens dentro desta pasta.

Como posso pegar essas imagens e exibir na view?

Comment: A versão do Laravel é 5.2 mesmo?

Comment: Sim essa mesmo.

Comment: a resposta não foi satisfatório, precisa entender mais alguma coisa, tem algo a dizer?

Answer (score 2):

Crie um [link simbólico](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Link-simbolico-e-hardlink) dentro da pasta `/public`. Como criar [link simbólico](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Link-simbolico-e-hardlink), exemplos aqui no [*SOPt*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)?:

- [Como listar os links simbólicos de uma pasta no Linux?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133502/como-listar-os-links-simb%C3%B3licos-de-uma-pasta-no-linux)
- [Linux - Link Simbolico + Dropbox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80718/linux-link-simbolico-dropbox)
- [Como criar um link simbólico para um código em Python no Linux?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96126/como-criar-um-link-simb%C3%B3lico-para-um-c%C3%B3digo-em-python-no-linux)

Todos os exemplos são para [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) `bash` e no `Windows` desde o `Windows Vista` é possível criar com o comando [`mklink`](http://Criando%20Link%20Simb%C3%B3lico%20no%20Windows):

*`Sintaxe`*

> `MKLINK [[/d] | [/h] | [/j]] <Link><Target>`

*Parâmetros*

> `/d` Cria um link simbólico do diretório. Por padrão, o mklink cria um
>   link simbólico do arquivo.
>
> `/h` Cria um vínculo real em vez de um vínculo simbólico.
>
> `/j` Cria uma junção de diretório.
>
> `<Link>` Especifica o nome do vínculo simbólico que está sendo criado.
>
> `<Target>` Especifica o caminho (relativo ou absoluto) ao qual se refere o novo vínculo simbólico.
>
> `/?` Exibe a Ajuda no prompt de comando.

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Microsoft TechNet -  MKLINK](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)</sub>

---

Na versão [laravel-5.3](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.3), com o comando `php artisan storage:link` cria um [link simbólico](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Link-simbolico-e-hardlink) para a pasta `public/storage`.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>**Observação:** no Windows desde do [Vista pode criar link simbólico](http://Criando%20Links%20Simb%C3%B3licos%20no%20Windows%20com%20Mklink) com o comando [`mklink`](http://Criando%20Link%20Simb%C3%B3lico%20no%20Windows)</sup>

***Referencias:***

- [Link Simbólico e `HardLink`](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Link-simbolico-e-hardlink)
- [Filesystem / Cloud Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem)
- [Criando Links Simbólicos no Windows com Mklink](https://marciocabreira.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/criando-links-simbolicos-no-windows-com-mklink/)
- [Criando Link Simbólico no Windows](http://www.jpandrade.com.br/criando-link-simblico-no-windows/)
- [Criando links simbólicos no Windows](https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2015/04/como-criar-links-simbolicos-no-windows-symlinks/)

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma mais simples seria:

asset("storage/app/public/banners/banner.png");